# Converting MultiDict to proper JSON

Tags: python, json, dictionary, flask

The MultiDict (ImmutableMultiDict) that i receive from posting a form using Flask (python) is

```
ImmutableMultiDict([
    ('disabled', 'False'), 
    ('disabled', 'False'), 
    ('debet', '11'), 
    ('debet', '21'), 
    ('date', '2016-11-17'), 
    ('kredit', '12'), 
    ('kredit', '22'), 
    ('record', '1901'), 
    ('record', '1902'), 
    ('description', 'Sales of inventory')
])
```

The form i post looks like

```
<form method="POST" action="/post">
    <input name="description" value="Sales of inventory" />
    <input name="date" value="2016-11-17" />
    <div class="group">
        <input name="record" value="1901" />
        <input name="debet" value="11" />
        <input name="kredit" value="12" />
        <input name="disabled" value="False" />
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <input name="record" value="1902" />
        <input name="debet" value="21" />
        <input name="kredit" value="22" />
        <input name="disabled" value="False" />
    </div>
</form>
```

I would like to convert this form (exclude description and date) input into a JSON format that looks like

```
data = [
    {
        "record": 1901,
        "debet": 11,
        "kredit": 12,
        "disabled": False
    },
    {
        "record": 1902,
        "debet": 21,
        "kredit": 22,
        "disabled": False
    }
]
```

Is there a good way to do this? I have tried loads of stuff, but I can't figure it out properly.

Comment: No, I don't see a good way to do that. The data you receive does not retain the structure of the posted form. You could assume that the first of each key appears with the first of the other keys and the second with the second, but I don't know if that's guaranteed anywhere.

Comment: What if you used `input name="record[1]"` and `input name="record[2]"` in your form? Does that change the `ImmutableDict` that you receive?

Comment: Python and Flask doesn't accept a post message in json. The response is `ImmutableMultiDict([('record[2]', '1902'), ('disabled[2]', 'False'), ('record[1]', '1901'), ('date', '2016-11-17'), ('debet[1]', '11'), ('kredit[2]', '22'), ('kredit[1]', '12'), ('debet[2]', '21'), ('description', 'Domännamn'), ('disabled[1]', 'False')])`

Comment: Once you set the right field names for inputs you can parse the `ImmutableDict` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely cannot change how the data is sent, and you're sure that the data is always sent in the same order as the form (**Make sure of this, otherwise there is no way to tell which values go together**), then you can do something like this:

```
fields = ['record', 'debet', 'kredit', 'disabled']

num_values = len(form_data.getlist(fields[0]))

data = []

for i in range(num_values):
    data.append({field: form_data.getlist(field)[i] for field in fields})
```

HOWEVER, I wouldn't recommend this.  At the end of the day, you are *somehow* generating new inputs dynamically, since it seems like you have a dynamic number of fields, so why not just change the names to record1, record2, etc. when you're doing this?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of kiran.koduru I solve my specific problem with

```
def jsonify_data(N, data=[]):
    totalRows = int((len(N) - 2) / 4)
    row = {}
    for i in range(totalRows):
        for (key, value) in N.items():
            if key == 'record[' + str(i) + ']':
                row['record'] = value
            if key == 'debet[' + str(i) + ']':
                row['debet'] = value
            if key == 'kredit[' + str(i) + ']':
                row['kredit'] = value
            if key == 'disabled[' + str(i) + ']':
                row['disabled'] = value
        if(row):
            data.append(row)
            row = {}
    return data
```

And then I just use the received form as

```
jsonify_data(request.form)
```

I have defined `data=[]` so that I can use it later on, and combining what we already have in the database as

```
jsonify_data(request.form, json_data_from_database)
```

EDIT:
The database I use is PostgreSQL with SQLAlchemy and I recognized that I couldn't update the value in the database. I added a line that copies the previous data, and don't use it straight away to solve the problem.

```
def jsonify_data(N, P):
    // ADDED THIS
    data = P[:]
    totalRows = int((len(N) - 2) / 4)
    row = {}
    for i in range(totalRows):
        for (key, value) in N.items():
            if key == 'record[' + str(i) + ']':
                row['record'] = value
            if key == 'debet[' + str(i) + ']':
                row['debet'] = value
            if key == 'kredit[' + str(i) + ']':
                row['kredit'] = value
            if key == 'disabled[' + str(i) + ']':
                row['disabled'] = value
        if(row):
            data.append(row)
            row = {}
    return data
```

Comment: Excellent :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery to do this. It just means instead of posting from the form, you post using ajax. In the code below, the name and value from each child in a group is collected into an object called 'group'. Once all names and values have been collected for a group, the 'group' object is pushed onto an array called 'data'. This array of objects is JSON.stringified and posted to flask via $.ajax().

The following is the html/javascript side:

```
<!--index.html-->
<html>
<head>
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input name="description" value="Sales of inventory" />
        <input name="date" value="2016-11-17" />
        <div class="group">
            <input name="record" value="1901" />
            <input name="debet" value="11" />
            <input name="kredit" value="12" />
            <input name="disabled" value="False" />
        </div>
        <div class="group">
            <input name="record" value="1902" />
            <input name="debet" value="21" />
            <input name="kredit" value="22" />
            <input name="disabled" value="False" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <button id='submitBtn'>Submit</button>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#submitBtn').on('click', function() {
                var data = [];
                $('.group').each(function(group_idx) {
                    var group_this = $(this);
                    var group = {};
                    group_this.children('input').each(function(input_idx) {
                        var input_this = $(this);
                        group[input_this.attr('name')] = input_this.val();
                    });
                    data.push(group);
                });
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/post',
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                }).done(function(resp) {
                    console.log('done');
                }).fail(function(resp) {
                    console.log('failed');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

And then in flask you can use request.json to retrieve the data.

```
from pprint import pprint 
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/post', methods=['POST'])
def post():
    data = request.json
    pprint(data)
    return redirect('/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Good solution if you want to include javascript. I want the form to work no matter if you have javascript or not enabled, therefore I do believe my solution is better.